# Prove that $B = (A \cap B) \cup (A' \cap B)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I started using the distributive property to open the expression but it goes on and on.

$ (A \cap B) \cup (A' \cap B) = B \cap (A \cup B) \cap (A' \cup B)$ (Using distributive property)

If I start opening by distributive, the expression gets bigger and bigger, how should I solve it?

Comment: If $b\in B$, either $b\in A$ or $b\notin A$

Comment: Try using the distributive property to factor out $B$ - ie "apply it backwards".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B = (A \cup A') \cap B = (A \cap B) \cup (A' \cap B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $ x \in B$

- If $x \in A$, then $x \in (A \cap B) \implies x \in (A \cap B)\cup (A' \cap B)$.
- if $x \notin A$, then $x \in A'$.  This implies $x \in (A' \cap B) \implies x \in (A \cap B)\cup (A' \cap B)$.

Thus $B \subseteq (A \cap B)\cup (A' \cap B) \ \ (*)$

---

Take $x \in (A \cap B)\cup (A' \cap B)$. Then, definitely, $x \in B$.

Thus $ (A \cap B)\cup (A' \cap B) \subseteq B \ \ (**)$

---

$(*) \land (**)\implies B = (A \cap B)\cup (A' \cap B) \ \ \blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

For a visual explanation, this venn diagram should make it clear:

[image: venn diagram]

$B$ is the union of the two highlighted areas, $A \cap B$ and $A' \cap B$. Therefore, $B = (A \cap B) \cup (A' \cap B)$.