# Is $(B' \cap C' \cap A) \cup (C \cap A) \cup (B \cap A) = A$ always true, or only sometimes?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is this true, always, or do exceptions exist?
> $$(B' \cap C' \cap A) \cup (C \cap A) \cup (B \cap A) = A$$

I can't seem to find any... but Mathematica tells me it's only true sometimes...

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For any sets $X$ and $Y$, it is always true that $$X = (X\cap Y)\cup (X\cap Y').$$
Your formula is a special form of this one, with $X = A$ and $Y = B\cup C$.

I tried your formula in Wolfram too, and it says it's true for any $A, B, C$. Perhaps a typo?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo... Just out of curiosity, is there a name for that rule you gave?  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Gothenburgresident I don't know a name for it, but it is easily provable.

Comment: Ok, how would you prove it?

Comment: @Gothenburgresident I hope this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850982/prove-that-b-a-cap-b-cup-a-cap-b